# how can i set the id of product to their own group?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

**Problem**
*The problem I'm facing is that i have a same products with different descriptions, so i had to group them in a dropdown respectively. Now when i change the value in the dropdown of the product, it changes the values in only the first product retrieved. The code and the screenshot of the issues are attached below.*

**Code**

```
<script>
   $(document).on("change", '.tranactionID', function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           $('#id_price').text($(this).children(":selected").attr("price"));
           $('#id_sale_price').text($(this).children(":selected").attr("sale_price"));
           let id = $('#ItemID').find(":selected").attr('transID');
           console.log('Id : ',id)
         let Url = `{% url 'cart:cart_add' 0 %}`.replace(0,id);
         $('#transactionIDValue').attr('action', Url);
         let formAction = $('#transactionIDValue').attr('action')
         let formAction2 = $('#transactionIDValue').prop('action')
         console.log('form action relative  url : ',formAction)
         console.log('form action full url : ',formAction2)
    });
</script>

{% regroup transaction by productID as ProductList %}
  {% for productID in ProductList %}
  <div class="col-sm-3" id="productID" >
    <div class="product">
      <a href="{% url 'main:product-detail' productID.grouper.id %}" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" src={{productID.grouper.product_image.url}} alt="" height="200px">
        <span class="status" id="discount">%</span>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </a>
      <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
        <h3><a href="#">{{productID.grouper}}</a></h3>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="pricing">
            <p class="price"><span class="mr-2 price-dc" id='id_price'>Rs. </span><span class="price-sale" id='id_sale_price'>Rs. </span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
          
          <select class="tranactionID" id="ItemID" style="width: 250px;">
            <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>
              Select an Option
          </option>
            {% for val in productID.list %}
                <option transID={{val.id}} price={{val.Price}} sale_price={{val.get_sale}} class="price_value" >{{val.AUID}} - {{val.Description}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
         
         
        <!-- <div class="bottom-area d-flex px-3">
          <div class="m-auto d-flex"> -->
            <form id='transactionIDValue' class="d-inline" method="post">
              {{cart_product_form}}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2" value="Add To Cart">
              
              
              <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2">Add to Cart</button> -->
            </form>
          <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

**Output**
[image]

*Now in the image attached above the issue is that i have change the value in the dropdown list of oranges but the price is updated at onions and even the id is passed to the add to cart button of onion. Can anyone help me with this issue.*

Comment: [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-class) is for grouping elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use same `ids` for mutliple elements so change them to class selector . Then , inside your event handler use `.closest()` and `.find()` to change required elements values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("change", '.tranactionID', function(event) {
  //get closest outer div.. 
  var selector = $(this).closest(".productID")
  //find to get required elements..
  selector.find('.id_price').text($(this).children(":selected").attr("price"));
  selector.find('.price-sale').text($(this).children(":selected").attr("sale_price"));
  let id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('transID');
  let Url = `{% url 'cart:cart_add' 0 %}`.replace(0, id);
  selector.find("form").attr('action', Url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added class-->
<div class="col-sm-3 productID">
  <div class="product">
    <a href="{% url 'main:product-detail' productID.grouper.id %}" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" src={{productID.grouper.product_image.url}} alt="" height="200px">
      <span class="status discount">%</span>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
      <h3><a href="#">Somethings,,</a></h3>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="pricing">
          <!--added class-->
          <p class="price"><span class="mr-2 price-dc id_price">Rs. </span> <span class="price-sale">Rs. </span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <select class="tranactionID" style="width: 250px;">
        <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>
          Select an Option
        </option>

        <option transID=1 price=234 sale_price=55 class="price_value">1 - abc</option>
        <option transID=1 price=224 sale_price=55 class="price_value">2 - abc3</option>

      </select>


      <form id='transactionIDValue' class="d-inline" method="post">

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2" value="Add To Cart">
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 productID">
  <div class="product">
    <a href="{% url 'main:product-detail' productID.grouper.id %}" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" src={{productID.grouper.product_image.url}} alt="" height="200px">
      <span class="status discount">%</span>
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="text py-3 pb-4 px-3 text-center">
      <h3><a href="#">Something</a></h3>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="pricing">
          <p class="price"><span class="mr-2 price-dc id_price">Rs. </span> <span class="price-sale">Rs. </span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <select class="tranactionID" style="width: 250px;">
        <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>
          Select an Option
        </option>
        <option transID=2 price=234 sale_price=55 class="price_value">1 - abc</option>
        <option transID=2 price=224 sale_price=55 class="price_value">2 - abc3</option>

      </select>


      <form class="d-inline" method="post">

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2" value="Add To Cart">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```